# A book about an alien boy living on earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I vaguely remember the book, it was about an alien boy who lived on Earth with his father.

I kinda remember the name being "something"-head.

Comment: @Möoz Please don't be so quick to close answerable questions. Howarth's *MapHead* may not be the ***only*** book titled "something-head" about an alien boy living on Earth with his father, but I'm pretty sure it's the most notable one, having won the *Guardian* award for children's fiction.

Comment: Guy with the cool shirt, please confirm whether *MapHead*, suggested in an answer below, is or is not the book you are looking for. If it's the right book, you don't have to post a comment, you can simply "[accept](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)" the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps [*MapHead*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?24741) by [Lesley Howarth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesley_Howarth)? Originally published as [*MapHead*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?17489) in 1994, it won the 1995 [Guardian Children's Fiction Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardian_Children%27s_Fiction_Prize). It was followed by a 1997 sequel [*MapHead 2*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?910466) aka *MapHead: The Return*, and a 2005 omnibus edition [*MapHead: The complete story in one volume*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?910479).

From a review at [The Bookbag](http://www.thebookbag.co.uk/reviews/index.php?title=Maphead_by_Lesley_Howarth):

> MapHead and his father Ran are of the Subtle World. Ran can travel through time, make things disappear and erase human memories. MapHead can flash the map of any place across his face and bald scalp. MapHead is a halfling and now he is almost 12, Ran has brought him to meet his human mother. As they need to pass for humans, they've taken new names - Boothe and Powers, from a random movie - practised their English, and enrolled MapHead at the same school as his half-brother.